# How to set a count value (badge) for a textview in android using java (Not for an icon or any button or any other nav items)

Tags: java, android, textview

How to set a count value (badge) for a textview in android (Not for an icon or any button or any other nav items)

Image https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJcyC.png

I need to set a count value for a TextView in android. Now i have set like with hyphen in same line. But I need as a badge.

My code

```
 private void setText(@NonNull TextView view, @StringRes int stringRes, int count) {
        Utils.clear(mTextView);
        view.setText(mTextiew
                .append(getResources().getString(stringRes))
                .append(SharedStrings.HYPHEN)
                .append(count);
               
    }
```

Comment: don't think this question has anything to do with android studio :)

Comment: I don't get why ONLY text views?  You have some libraries out there and they are probably only for buttons but you can use buttons and with using the style attribute you can make them look exactly like your regular TextView. Thing is, I don't know if any of these libraries is working with TextView or not but there is always a solution to make it yourself, I did it before but it's not that easy.

Answer (score 0):

In case you like a native solution, you could look into [BadgeDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/badge/BadgeDrawable).

Two caveats:

- Note: This is still under development and may not support the full range of customization Material Android components generally support (e.g. themed attributes).
- You can't set the badge text, only `int`s, but this seems fine for your usecase